# string comparison "=" != "+" , incorrect results

Tags: javascript, string

Task is to check whether string results true or false for following given condition:

If a letter a to z occurs it must have '+' before and after the particular letter
This works fine expect the case when '=' comes before or after the letter.
Why this condition is wrong for '=' ? 
This code returns true for these strings 
Thanks

```js
function SimpleSymbols(str) { 
    var temp=str.split("")
    if(temp.length==1 || temp.length==2 )
    return false;
    for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
        if(temp[i]>='a' && temp[i]<='z'){
            if(i===0 || i===(temp.length-1)|| 
            (temp[i-1]!=='+' && temp[i+1]!=='+')){
                return false;
            }   
        }
    } 
  return true; 
}
```

Comment: "+d===+a+" gives true, it should be false , same goes with  "=d+==+a+"

Comment: for rest of the cases, other than '=', code works fine

Comment: I would have solved this problem using regexes

Comment: Why have you split the string into an array? Strings can be iterated through anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition `(temp[i-1]!=='+' && temp[i+1]!=='+')` is only true if both the character before *and* after the letter are not pluses. If one of them is a plus sign the condition is false.

You need to change the logical and to an or operator: `(temp[i-1]!=='+' || temp[i+1]!=='+')`

#### Background: De Morgan's Laws

The original condition is that a letter is surrounded by plus signs:

```
temp[i-1] === '+' && temp[i+1] === '+'
```

In your `if` clause you test that this condition is not matched. So, the original condition becomes:

```
!(temp[i-1] === '+' && temp[i+1] === '+')
```

To transform this into a condition using not-equals, you need to apply [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws#Negation_of_a_conjunction) which basically say that a logical *and* becomes an *or* and vice-versa if you factor in a negation. This makes the resulting condition:

```
temp[i-1] !== '+' || temp[i+1] !== '+'
```

Comment: @charlietfl: If either before or after is not a `+` it should be false, not only if both are not a `+`. This solution is correct.

Answer (score 2):

```js
<!-- I think you should change the condition operator -->

function SimpleSymbols(str) { 
    var temp=str.split("")
    if(temp.length==1 || temp.length==2 )
    return false;
    for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
        if(temp[i]>='a' && temp[i]<='z'){
            if(i===0 || i===(temp.length-1)|| 
            (temp[i-1]!=='+' || temp[i+1]!=='+')){
                return false;
            }   
        }
    } 
  return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint: check out these strings too, they all return true even though they should return false.

- `"+a4"`
- `"1a+"`
- `"%a+"`

Let's simplify your condition:

```
str[i-1] !== '+' && str[i+1] !== '+'
```

is the same as

```
!(str[i-1] === '+' || str[i+1] === '+')
```

This makes it easier to see what you were really checking.

We can see now that the condition `str[i-1] !== '+' && str[i+1] !== '+'` returns true only if neither of those two characters are a `+`.

You want it to return true if at least one is not a `+`. So you should use this instead:

```
str[i-1] !== '+' || str[i+1] !== '+'
```

---

I re-wrote your code with this correct condition here:

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) { 
    if (str.length == 1 || str.length == 2) return false;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') {
            if (i === 0 || i === (str.length-1) || (str[i-1] !== '+' || str[i+1] !== '+')) {
                return false;
            }   
        }
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

---

Note: regular expressions can help out a lot with pattern-matching in strings like this.

E.g. your whole function would have simply become the regex:

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) {
  return !str.match(/[^+][a-z][^+]/) && str.length > 2;
}
```